# Terminating actor hierarchy

Tags: java, garbage-collection, akka, lifecycle

I have three actors. Actor A spawns actor B and actor C for performing various tasks and does not depend upon the result of actor B and C

Actors B and C are created in the following way:

```
ActorRef actorB = this.getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ActorB.class, t));
actorB.tell(new msg, getSelf());

ActorRef actorC = this.getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ActorC.class, t));
actorC.tell(new anothermsg, getSelf());
```

How do I ensure that this hierarchy is torn down after the task is complete by each actor?

Do I send an explicit poisonPill message to both actors B and C?
Or will this be taken care of ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want B and C to stop independently of A, then the easiest way would be for them to call `context stop self` after their job is complete. A can be notified of this events by registering to them via - e.g. - `context watch b`.

If, otherwise, you want the whole hierarchy to stop at the same time - i.e. when A terminates - then you only need to stop A, as all its children will be automatically stopped as a consequence.

For a more comprehensive coverage of the topic, see [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/actors.html#Stopping_actors).